# Collapse nav bar in css3

Tags: html, css, navbar

I created a website, which does not contain any collapsed navigation bar. So when the resolution is reduced, the menu will be shown as a stack.

Most of my web page becomes destroyed. I have no time to convert my design to bootstrap now.
Is it possible to create responsive, collapsed "navigation bar" with css3. Without using bootstrap or JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it is possible ... check for `media queries`

Comment: FYI; http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thanks for the information @Coops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are two ways you can target screen sizes with css:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 719px) and (min-width: 420px){
   .your-class-here {
    display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```

a bit on them here from W3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

And this page is good too: http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/